# ¿cómo obtener el valor de una celda en un Data Grid en Compact Framework con C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datatable, datagrid, embebido

Tengo un pequeño problema, ojala y me puedan apoyar, y es el siguiente:

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para un dispositivo con Windows Embedded y la estoy haciendo en el Compact Framework 3.5; no en el *Framework normal*.

En la aplicación se mostrara una tabla, la cual tendrá 2 columnas: *SKU* y *Producto*. La tabla la hago con `DataTable` y esos datos los muestro con un `DataGrid`.

Lo que quiero hacer es, cuando el usuario presione una fila, obtener el *SKU* de la fila que seleccionó y poder hacer una consulta en base a eso; pero no encuentro la forma de hacerlo con un evento o algo en el `DataGrid`. Para este CF no viene `DataGridView`, con el que se puede hacer perfectamente lo que quiero.

¿Existe alguna otra manera de mostrar una tabla y obtener el valor de lo que seleccionó el usuario?